# update time of each record in MongoDB

Tags: php, mongodb

MongoDB's ObjectId has a getTimestamp() method that returns time when the record was inserted. Is there a similar method for getting time of last update or should I use a separate column to save this data?

Using PHP (if it matters).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't store the last update so that's something you'll have to store yourself through your application in a separate field.