# MongoDB: automagically capture created/updated time in the database (not the application)

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I'd like to capture inserts and updates to documents that get inserted into a MongoDB database. For inserts, it's possible to do this because the document create time is encoded in the ObjectID.

For example, I can insert a document:

```
> db.test.insertOne(
...    { docnum: 1}
... )
{
    "acknowledged" : true,
    "insertedId" : ObjectId("58bcee87fcf4a79f8157dfad")
}
```

... and then retrieve the timestamp for that document:

```
> ObjectId("58bcee87fcf4a79f8157dfad").getTimestamp()
ISODate("2017-03-06T05:07:19Z")
```

If I then update that document:

```
> db.test.updateOne(
...    { docnum: 1 },
...    {
...      $set: { "text": "Some text." }
...    }
... )
{ "acknowledged" : true, "matchedCount" : 1, "modifiedCount" : 1 }
```

... the document timestamp doesn't change because the timestamp is the create timestamp and not a last updated timestamp:

```
> db.test.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("58bcee87fcf4a79f8157dfad"), "docnum" : 1, "text" : "Some text." }

> ObjectId("58bcee87fcf4a79f8157dfad").getTimestamp()
ISODate("2017-03-06T05:07:19Z")
```

An obvious solution would be to change the application to include the updated timestamp. In this case, I don't control the application, only the MongoDB.

If this were MySQL, the updated/created timestamps could be added:

```
CREATE TABLE my_table (
  ...,
  updated TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  created TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Is there a MongoDB equivant to this? I read that MongoDB doesn't support triggers or stored procedures, but am curious to know if there's a commonly used workaround/hack to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [update time of each record in MongoDB](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9462656/update-time-of-each-record-in-mongodb)

Answer (score 2):

MongoDB does not save any timestamp itself. If you are using Mongoose then you can specify to store timestamps on create/update

```
var thingSchema = new Schema({..}, { timestamps: true });
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps